# How to draw a circle in Haskell using opengl

Tags: opengl, haskell, geometry

I want to know how to draw a circle. From my understanding, this can only be done using a lot of triangles. However, I can't find a tutorial that explains it clearly enough for me to understand and replicate. Does anybody know any *good* tutorial sites/can explain to me how to make one?

Comment: Well, the question is a bit broad. What do you actually know? Besides that, a mass of triangles is not the only option. Another good idea is a simple textured quad (just two triangles) with an alpha texture (completely transparent everywhere outside the circle).

Comment: Well, compared to what you just said, absolutely nothing. Like I said, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's any way to draw a *true* circle in OpenGL, but there are two basic ways to approximate it:

- Use a texture: Make sure that the texture supports transparency and that you have blending set appropriately (something you should find in any OpenGL introduction), then just load an image file containing a circle and apply that to a square. To draw lots of small circles (for a particle engine, say) this is the way to go.
- Draw a polygon with lots of sides: Either a fan of triangles from one corner, or a bunch of slices meeting in the center. The more triangles you use, the closer it will look to a true circle, but those are a finite resource and you don't always want to spend lots of polygons to approximate curves. This is best if you only have a few circles that will be drawn large enough to make texturing awkward.

For an example of the latter approach, you can look at [the `graphics-drawingcombinators` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/graphics-drawingcombinators/1.4.1/doc/html/Graphics-DrawingCombinators.html#v%3acircle), which uses a 24-sided polygon. For examples of the former, any tutorial on using textures will do.

Comment: ok so just a picture of a circle with a transparent background?

Comment: Of course one can draw a (nearly) perfect circle on the fragment level. Using a fragment shader, discard all fragments outside the circle radius.

Comment: In my game programming exploits, I found that an 18-gon to a 24-gon will appear very circular if it does not get too large.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help get started:

```
circle (x, y) radius divs = map toPoint angles where 
    arc       = 2.0 * pi / fromIntegral divs
    toPoint a = (x + cos a * radius, y + sin a * radius)
    angles    = map ((*arc) . fromIntegral) [0..divs]
```

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1 shows the basics of setting up a window, and how to use HOpenGL.

```
renderFan points = do
    renderPrimitive TriangleFan $ mapM_ (\(x, y) -> vertex (Vertex2 x y)) points
```

Then create a fan by including the centre point e.g:

```
renderCircle centre radius divs = renderFan (centre : circle centre radius divs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type Point = (Float, Float)
type Polygon = [Point]

circle :: Point -> Float -> Polygon
circle (x,y) r = map (\t -> (x+r*cos (t), y+r*sin (t))) [0,0.2..(2*pi)]

--            center  radius   
ball = circle (0,0.2) 0.2
```

Then it is useful to have

```
points2GL :: [Point] -> [(GLfloat,GLfloat)]
points2GL l = [ (realToFrac x, realToFrac y) | (x,y) <- l ]

glPoints2Vertexes pts = mapM_ (\(x, y) -> vertex $ Vertex2 x y) pts

points2Vertexes pts = glPoints2Vertexes (points2GL pts)
```

so, you render the ball doing

```
renderPrimitive Polygon (points2Vertexes ball)
```